# Why is the TermQuery in elasticsearch so slow?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been using es 5.4.3 for multi-index searching. I used the profile API to trace the search procedure, and found out that one of the 'TermQuery' took more than 160ms! I'm new to es and lucene, but I've heard about that termquery in lucene is very fast. This happened even after I put the 'fielddata' into memory(I will show how my index is set up below), I'm not so confident in my mappings, I hope some master can figure out my mistake and solved the problem. Any instructions for me to figure out where the problem is?
This mapping is derived from es 2.x, but official doc says it will do the transformation automatically.

```
new_mappings = {
        "properties": {
            "did": {"type": "long", "index": "not_analyzed"},
            "title": {"type": "string", "index": "analyzed", "fielddata": {"loading": "eager"}},
            "title_embed": {"type": "double", "index": "no"},
            "entity": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed", "fielddata": {"loading": "eager"}},
            "tag": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
            "aliases": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
            "entity_with_field": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed", "fielddata": {"loading": "eager"}},
            "original_title": {"type": "string", "index": "analyzed", "analyzer": "standard", "fielddata": {"loading": "eager"}},
            "did3": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
            "title_entity": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed", "fielddata": {"loading": "eager"}},
        }
    }
```

```
              {
                "type" : "TermQuery",
                "description" : "title:cure",
                "time" : "163.5755780ms",
                "time_in_nanos" : 163575578,
                "breakdown" : {
                  "score" : 72259602,
                  "build_scorer_count" : 19,
                  "match_count" : 0,
                  "create_weight" : 35370852,
                  "next_doc" : 55374841,
                  "match" : 0,
                  "create_weight_count" : 1,
                  "next_doc_count" : 71435,
                  "score_count" : 71416,
                  "build_scorer" : 427412,
                  "advance" : 0,
                  "advance_count" : 0
                }
              },
              {
                "type" : "TermQuery",
                "description" : "title:fever",
                "time" : "0.2344140000ms",
                "time_in_nanos" : 234414,
                "breakdown" : {
                  "score" : 0,
                  "build_scorer_count" : 19,
                  "match_count" : 0,
                  "create_weight" : 230746,
                  "next_doc" : 0,
                  "match" : 0,
                  "create_weight_count" : 1,
                  "next_doc_count" : 0,
                  "score_count" : 0,
                  "build_scorer" : 3648,
                  "advance" : 0,
                  "advance_count" : 0
                }
```

Comment: Can you also show your query?

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot that: {
    "profile": true,
    "query": {
        "match": {"title": "cure fever"}
    }
}
@Val

Comment: It's funny because your mapping doesn't match at all with the sample documents you shared.

Comment: Also try to remove the `profile: true` parameter as that definitely increases the time the query takes to execute.

Comment: 'your mapping doesn't match at all with the sample documents you shared' what do you mean? @Val .  And online query which has removed 'profile' is also slow

Comment: For instance, there is no `title` field int he sample documents you shared... Look at the fields in your mapping and the fields in the documents, most are different

Comment: "title": {"type": "string", "index": "analyzed", "fielddata": {"loading": "eager"}},
mapping has 'title' indeed @Val

Comment: Yes, but your documents don't. Look again

Comment: @Val Could you point out?

Comment: Tell me the value of the title field in the two sample documents that you have shared? I don't see any title fields